# How to create unique index for both cases

Tags: postgresql, index, unique-constraint

I have table in PostgreSQL with `sender_id` and `receiver_id` and a unique index:

```
add_index :my_table, [:sender_id, :recipient_id], unique: true
```

Table will created, if sender_id: 1, and recipient_id: 2.

I can create another table, with sender_id: 2, and recipient_id: 1. But table with this ids, (but in different order) already exists.

How can I make unique for both cases?

- sender_id: 1, recipient_id: 2
- sender_id: 2, recipient_id: 1

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: You should ask database questions in a database language :)  Why would you create two tables for the same sort of data? Or you mean rows there?  Finally, does your requirement mean that if there is a message (or whatever you store there) from A to B, B cannot answer to A?

Answer (score 3):

For Postgres and Oracle:

```
create unique index unique_combinations 
    on my_table (least(sender_id, recipient_id), greatest(sender_id, recipient_id));
```